# Hook a tab-icon onto an image

Tags: javascript, html, css, tabs, image

I'd like to put some sort of a tab at the bottom border of an image displayed in a gallery. This tab should be adjacent to the image-border without one pixel space.

Clicking this tab would then trigger a small java-script to display the content of div #Metadata

```
function showMetadata()
{document.getElementById("Metadata").style.display="block";}
```

The div #Metadata displayed contains a button to 'close' the display of #Metadata.

```
function hideMetadata()
{document.getElementById("Metadata").style.display="none";}
```

The two functions above work fine.

The problem I have is to 'hook' that tab-icon to the image(s) in xhtml. Per page the images vary in numbers and sizes so a positioning using pixel values in CSS is no the solution.

I assume this problem has been solved - I just don't know about the solution.

Also there might be a clever way eg. using jquery.

Thanks for replies.

Comment: Can we see html and css? It might be possible with just css even if the images are different sizes.

Comment: Here is the URL to the live Web-pages in question.
http://preview.tinyurl.com/7p7cznx
It's functional, but still ugly.
It's the div #metadata_img

Comment: The image itself is enclosed in an <a hreF= , so clicking the image proceeds to the next one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you put the images in a div container? That way you can just add an absolutely positioned "tab" set to under the image.

http://jsfiddle.net/86hWH/1/